# How to remove dynamically fields from a dataclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I want to inherit my dataclass but remove some of its fields.
How can I do that in runtime so I don't need to copy all of the members one by one?

Example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int
    d: int

@remove("c", "d")
class B(A):
    pass
```

Such that `A` would have `a, b, c, d` defined and `B` would only have `a` and `b` defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove the particular fields from the `__annotations__` dictionary as well as from `__dataclass_fields__` and then rebuild our class using `dataclasses.make_dataclass`:

```py
def remove(*fields):
    def _(cls):
        fields_copy = copy.copy(cls.__dataclass_fields__)
        annotations_copy = copy.deepcopy(cls.__annotations__)
        for field in fields:
            del fields_copy[field]
            del annotations_copy[field]
        d_cls = dataclasses.make_dataclass(cls.__name__, annotations_copy)
        d_cls.__dataclass_fields__ = fields_copy
        return d_cls
    return _
```

**Note** that we copy the annotations and the fields in order to not affect A. otherwise it would remove these fields from A as well and any other attempt to inherit A and remove again a field which we already removed would lead to an error. I.e:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int
    d: int

@remove("c", "d")
class B(A):
    pass

@remove("b", "c")
class C(A):
    pass
```

This would give us a `KeyError` since we already removed "c" and this is no longer exists in A's dictionary.

Comment: an amazing self answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative implementation.

```
from dataclasses import make_dataclass, fields, dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int
    d: int

def remove(*exclusions):
    def wrapper(cls):
        new_fields = [(i.name, i.type, i) for i in fields(cls) if i.name not in exclusions]
        return make_dataclass(cls.__name__, new_fields)
    return wrapper

@remove('b', 'a')
class B(A):
    pass

foo = B(1, 2)
baz = A(1, 2, 3, 4)
print(foo)
print(baz)
```

Although while writing it out I realized that it might be better suited as a class factory function given that instance checks such as `isinstance(foo, A)` would fail and users of the code might find it surprising.

```
from dataclasses import make_dataclass, fields, dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int
    d: int

def factory(base, name, exclusions):
    new_fields = [(i.name, i.type, i) for i in fields(base) if i.name not in exclusions]
    return make_dataclass(name, new_fields)

B = factory(base=A, name='B', exclusions=('b', 'c'))
foo = B(1, 2)
baz = A(1, 2, 3, 4)
print(foo)
print(baz)
```